# How to stop writing in textbox by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to enter only 3 words in a textbox. My JavaScript code is below:

```
jQuery('#Txt_Report').keyup(function (event) {
   if (event.which == 32) {
      count = jQuery('#Txt_Report').val().split(' ').length;
      if (count > 2) {
         /////////////
         //How can I stop entering text in txt_report anymore?
         /////////////
      });
   }
}
```

As you see, I want to block user to not to enter more than 3 words. If someone knows how to handle this please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't `preventDefault` using `keyup`. Using [`keydown`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) or [`keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) should work. Here is the example:

```
$('#Txt_Report').keypress(function(e) {
   if (e.which == 32) {
      var count = this.value.split(' ').length;
      if (count > 2) {
         e.preventDefault();
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: @enginbilici also not that you should use `var` for count. Also you don't need to use `jQuery` again to get the `<input/>`. You can just use `this.value`

Comment: +1 The only correct answer. `keydown` is too early, and will not prevent all keystrokes. In fact, only the `keypress` event can cancel all possible occurrences of a key event. Using `keyup` is too late, since the default behaviour (ie, "filling a text box") has already occurred.

Comment: @RobW I never knew `keydown` could be too early. Thanks for the update. However, in jQuery's keydown documentation, they use `preventDefault()` on keydown. Is that a mistake?

Comment: No, because the `keydown` can effectively be used to detect when a key is pressed *down*. If you're developing a function to capture hotkeys, the keydown event should be used, because it does not make sense to capture a keypress of, say, `[E]` multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

Use `event.preventDefault();` with `keydown` (as suggested by the comments)

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/wTvmz/

```
jQuery('#Txt_Report').keydown(function (event) {
   if (event.which == 32) {
      count = jQuery('#Txt_Report').val().split(' ').length;
      if (count > 2) {
         event.preventDefault();
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: I think the `keyup` event is too late for this. You'd need `keydown`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the disabled attribute to disabled.

```
 jQuery('#Txt_Report').keyup(function (event) {
   if (event.which == 32) {
      count = jQuery('#Txt_Report').val().split(' ').length;
      if (count > 2) {
         /////////////
         //How can I stop entering text in txt_report anymore?
         /////////////
         jQuery('#Txt_Report').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      });
   }
}
```

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

Comment: This is not a great answer. Once they input is disabled, there is no way to enable it again!! :)

Comment: Thanks for your ansver saratis,
I want to force the user to enter 3 words only. If he tries to enter more, I wont let him. But in this case, he may delete some of words and writes something different. I mean, what I want is to only blocking user, and not to disable anyting.

Comment: Right, thats changes things. @Amir, of course you can enable it, just remove the attr.

Answer (score 0):

Why not utilize "keypress" and return false?

http://jsfiddle.net/kW9tF/

```
$('#txt').keypress(function (event) {
  return false;
});
```

Updated code example: http://jsfiddle.net/kW9tF/1/

```
$('#txt').keypress(function (event) {
    var count = $(this).val().split(' ').length;
    if (count > 2) {
      return false;
    };
 });
```

Comment: Don't use `return false` http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: Good idea, thank you Kris Krause. But here, the user may want to delete one of words...

Comment: Amir, understood but I see no reason given the question context to not stopPropagation.